# In a Rails project, we put all constants definition in config/environment.rb and more particular ones in config/environments/development.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is that the usual convention?  The more general constants in `config/environment.rb`, and more particular ones, such as `HOST_NAME` for development mode
in `config/environments/development.rb` as `localhost:3000`, in `config/environments/production.rb` as `www.mygreatwebsite.com`, and they will automatically get included into the project?

Answer (score 4):

The config files test/production/development.rb are used when the rails application is started in one of these specific environments (test/production/development). The config.rb is used to define configuration which applies to **all** environments.

Comment: what about environment.rb and files in environments folder?